# Model class properties should private or public?

Tags: java, php, oop, model

I have question which has been going around in my mind since long.

My Model class should have properties private or public? (Below code is written in PHP but question applies in general for any language)

```
class Xyz extends Model {

    public function __call() {

    }

    public $description;

    public $title;
}
```

In above example I have public properties $description and $title. Should I make them private?

I update my model as follows

```
$x = new Xyz();
$x->title('Hello');
$x->description('Blah blah');
$x->save();
```

I can update and get them by using magic method __call. So why do we need to keep them public? I can make them private. But as I see all the frameworks around keep model properties public.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:**

In answers, everyone is saying follow encapsulation and use private methods. Good but no one has the answer why some PHP frameworks have model properties public ? There should be some reason, isn't it?

Comment: Keep all the properties as private. To encapsulate their values use getter and setter to get values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class fields should always be private. Getters and setters for the fields should be public. Aside from being standard, it is also good to have it this way so that you have the control to do what ever you want to the values that the client classes wants to set to you private fields.

For example, if you want to persist an object to a database, and one column is stated to be not null, and you are not sure if your client class will really return a non-null value, you can handle the null check inside the setter so that the values that you are about to persist to the db contains no null field, as what the table of your db demands.

Answer (score 3):

As per OOP, we need to follow encapsulation. Please make your properties `private` and have `public` accessors and mutators. but, it depends that your accessors and mutators can have other modifiers as well. But, The properties should be always `private`.

Answer (score 1):

The fields should always be private as per OOP encapsulation principle. Now the thing is with the getter and setter accessor methods.

The getter is usually safe to make it public. The only downside of it is that you will have to maintain backward compatibility between versions, as this will be part of the public contract of the class. So if the field is something that is part of the implementation rather than interface, than maybe you want to keep it protected.

As for the setter the better question is if to create one or not. If you want to keep your class immutable (or at least some parts of it) with all the advantages and disadvantages that comes from it, then you'll not be creating a setter at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make all properties as `private` in model class and if you have to encapsulate their value then you have to use appropriate `getters and setters` to get and set their values.